# Integrating Native SMS from React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, sms

I am attempting to integrate native SMS text capabilities from within React Native.  The reason for the native integration is none of the React Native solutions such as react-native-sms or react-native-communications support sending images as attachments at this time.

I have the call from React Native to iOS working but on the iOS side, I am receiving the following:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x10e86ba00> on <FooAppModule: 0x10de097e0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

My expectation was that the MFMessageComposeViewController would display with the text and image sent from the React Native application and would allow the user to press the send. The current code block in iOS looks like this:

```
@objc(FooAppModule)
class FooAppModule: UIViewController, 
MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

  var bridge: RCTBridge!
  var promiseRejectBlock: RCTPromiseRejectBlock!

   // Indicate whether or not a text message can be sent from the member's iOS device
  func canSendText() -> Bool {
    return MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()
  }

  // Configures and returns a MFMessageComposeViewController instance
  func configuredMessageComposeViewController(phoneNumber: String) {
    debugPrint("Phone number to be sent a text to", phoneNumber)

    let textMessageRecipients = [ phoneNumber ]

    let messageComposeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    messageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self  //  Make sure to set this property to self, so that the controller can be dismissed!
    messageComposeVC.recipients = textMessageRecipients
    messageComposeVC.body =  "Sending Text Message through SMS in Swift"

    self.present(messageComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate callback - dismisses the view controller when the user is finished with it
  func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) 
  {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  @objc func shareText(_ phoneNumber: String, imageBase64: String,
               resolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
               rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void     {
        if (canSendText()) {
          configuredMessageComposeViewController(phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
    }
  }
}
```

What piece of the puzzle am I missing?

Comment: in android you must add "Permission" but in IOS i don't know. :(

Comment: As the error message says, the view controller that has attempted to present the message compose view controller is not itself presented. Please edit your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: I have updated my initial question.